# RelativeLayout within GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, adapter

I am having a problem with this XML code :
When I am scrolling down the items that not see them are deleted. And when I try to scroll up I can not reach them anymore.
But, when i remove the RelativeLayout with the id="rlButtons" every thing wotks fine.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="4dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favourite_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favourite_button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Button1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class PictureGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  ICurrentAppData currentAppData = CurrentAppData.getInstance();
  private Activity activity;

  public PictureGridViewAdapter(Activity activity, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return currentAppData.getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final GridviewHodler holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, null);
      holder = new GridviewHodler();
      holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
      holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView
          .findViewById(R.id.progress);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
      holder = (GridviewHodler) convertView.getTag();
    return convertView;
  }
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="4dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favourite_button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Button1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favourite_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```